# Is there any way to toggle the height of a css element by clicking in another?

Tags: html, css

Im making an website to stream videos just for fun.
As i started triyng to do responsive design to get a good website on cellphones,tablets etc, i came across the difficulty of giving toggle to the height of a css element by clicking on another.

To reproduce the error you will need to get the code on a window with 768 or less width!
I´ve used bootstrap (or atleast tried).
I don´t know much about jquery and javascrpit.
I´ve tried this "onclick function": `onclick="document.getElementById('navbar-collapse').style.height='45rem';"`
By thhe way, if I have some general error in my code that you can note, 
I would appreciate for informing me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title>Fancy navbar login / sign in form - Bootsnipp.com</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">

body{
    background-color:#1d1d1d;
    padding:50px;
}

#login-dp{
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 14px 14px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
#login-dp .help-block{
    font-size:12px    
}
#login-dp .bottom{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    clear:both;
    padding:14px;
}
#login-dp .social-buttons{
    margin:12px 0    
}
#login-dp .social-buttons a{
    width: 49%;
}
#login-dp .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn-fb{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#3b5998;
}
.btn-fb:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#496ebc 
}
.btn-tw{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#55acee;
}
.btn-tw:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#59b5fa;
}
@media(max-width:768px){
    #login-dp{
        background-color: inherit;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #login-dp .bottom{
        background-color: inherit;
        border-top:0 none;
    }
    .left {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
        position: absolute;
        margin-bottom: 60%;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 50%;
    }
    .navbar-collapse{
        min-height: 25rem;
    }
    .navbar{
        background-color: #171717;
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
        width: 5rem;
    }
    .navbar-text{
        margin-top: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 0rem;
    }

}
.navbar-toggle{
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
}
.navbar-brand{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.collapse{
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{
    font-family: Ubuntu, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text{
    font-family: Ubuntu, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a>p{
    font-family: Ubuntu, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: green;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;   
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a>p span{
    font-family: Ubuntu, "helvetica neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: static;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(50%);
    width: 60rem;
  }
  .navbar{
    min-height: 6rem;
    background-color: #171717;
  }
  .navbar-text{
    margin-top: 13px;
  }
}

    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <div class="left">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><b>Filmes</b></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>Séries</b></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>FAQ</b></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="#"><p>Endereço Desbloqueado: <span>youtube.com</span></p></a></li>
    </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="navbar-text">Já tem uma conta?</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar-collapse').style.height='45rem';"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                     <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Login via
                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                                </div>
                                or
                                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to toggle the height of the navbar by clicking on the "login" button. But nothing happens when i click.

Comment: where is navbar-collapse?

Comment: I got this element on the "documentation" of this bootstrap navbar, but it is working, you can see thst if u reduce your internet window width to lower than 768px u will get the "mobile view" of the website and there the navbar  colapse work as the navbar background box wuen the menu icon is pressed, showing the login icon, the filmes session etc. Until now its all ok but if you click on the login button you will see that the navbar(navbar colase) don't get the right height. I need to toggle the navbar colapse height from 25rem to like 50rem by clicking on the login button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.left {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  position: relative;
}
```

Your issue can be fixed by setting the `position` of the element inside `navbar-collapse` to `relative` instead of using `absolute`. Now the height will be set automatically according to the content.

Now you can remove that onclick because you don't need to increase the height with static value and also the error is because there is no element with `id='navbar-collapse'`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this whenever i get home but this don't change the fact that i don't know how to toggle the height by clicking on the login button. For example when i open the login session i want the height of the navbar to be set to 50rem and when i close the login session i want the height to be 25rem again!

Comment: Please check this pen: https://codepen.io/varunraval/pen/MMyxzb, here I have created an example for you to explain how you can achieve that. You can replace the button with your login button and div with the navbar.